# Distributed compilation for Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, bazel, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to use `distcc` for speeding-up the Tensorflow compilation. My `distcc` installations (both on host and client) are working correctly with traditional source packages that use Makefiles for compilation (`make -j`). But apparently `bazel` does not use `distcc` for compiling the Tensorflow sources.

Note that the target platform is a Raspberry Pi 3 running Raspbian Jessy (Ubuntu), thus it is important to offload the compilation on a more powerful machine.

Do you have any experience or suggestions?

Comment: Can't you just cross compile on a workstation to Raspberry Pi 3?

Comment: Oops I hit enter too fast. I wanted to add that there is a prototype for distributed compilation for Bazel at https://bazel-review.googlesource.com/#/c/3110/, it is indeed a bit different than distcc (inside google we have another different implementation that is very specific to our infrastructure).

Comment: I am not familiar with Bazel and I did not find a tutorial for the cross-compilation targeting the ARM Cortex-A53. Do you have any?

Comment: There is something about Linaro Linux here: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/wiki/Building-with-a-custom-toolchain

We have a plan for providing a toolchain for cross compiling for RaspPI but it is not here yet

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  We are using bazel with distcc.  You have to write a CROSSTOOL file and then create a wrapper script for gcc that prepends distcc and then forwards the arguments to real gcc.